# GCSToBigQueryOperator failed with "Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields'"

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

here is the code i am trying to run, but it's failing.

```py
gcs_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id='gcs_to_bq',
            bucket=GCS_BUCKET_NAME,
            source_objects=[GCS_OBJECT_NAME],
            destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{DATASET_TABLE_NAME}",
            schema_fields="gs://bucket/path/my_sqchema.json",
            autodetect=False,
            dag=dag,
)
```

```
Error Log:Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields'
```

What's the mistake I am making, can not find out, any help would be appreciated.

Json schema file contains,

```json
[
   {
     "name": "col1",
     "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
     "name": "col2",
     "type": "STRING",
     "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
]
```

Comment: Can you try this in your code:`schema_fields=[ { "name": "col1", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE" }, { "name": "col2", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE" } ]`.Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: It was working, i am trying to make the schema dynamic in the pipeline.

Comment: @A_Sk I proposed you an answer. Can you check it please and tell me if it helps you to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To use a `Json` schema from a bucket, you have to use the `schema_object` param instead of `schema_fields`, example :

```py
gcs_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='gcs_to_bq',
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_NAME,
        source_objects=[GCS_OBJECT_NAME],
        destination_project_dataset_table=f"{DATASET_NAME}.{DATASET_TABLE_NAME}",
        schema_object="gs://bucket/path/my_sqchema.json",
        autodetect=False,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

The documentation for the `schema_object` field :

```py
    :param schema_object: If set, a GCS object path pointing to a .json file that
        contains the schema for the table. (templated)
        Parameter must be defined if 'schema_fields' is null and autodetect is False.
```